# how do I use progress monitor in eclipse plugin code?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, progress, monitor

In my eclipse plugin, I created an utility class that does some work when I create my files, with my wizard.

I´d like to show to user some text, warning him about what´s happening, in the progress bar.

How could I do this?
Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: my wizard calls my utility class, that unzips 2 ZIP files and import 2 projects into workspace. So, I´d like to show a message after each operation, like:

Unzipping file1...
Unzipping file2...
Importing project1...
Importing project2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Wizard class enable the progress monitor by calling

```java
setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
```

in the constructor.

You can then run your `IRunnableWithProgress` class with:

```java
IRunnableWithProgress runnable = new MyRunnable();

getContainer().run(true, true, runnable);
```

This can be in the Wizard or in a WizardPage.

The `IRunnableWithProgress` class might look like:

```java
private class MyRunnable implements IRunnableWithProgress
{
  @Override
  public void run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException
  {
    monitor.beginTask("title", progress count);

    try
     {
       ... your work
     }
    finally
     {
       monitor.done();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: didn´t get it... my class must implement IRunnableWithProgress ? or my wizard must do it?

Comment: You will usually have a separate class implementing `IRunnableWithProgress` but that is up to you.

Comment: I added more info to question...still didn´t get it though... :(

Comment: when I run this line:
getContainer().run(true, true, myRunnable);
get a CoreException: INvalid thread access

I´m calling it inside finishPage(), from my wizard class.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: `code`
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 0] Invalid thread access
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5358)
 at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.wizards.DesignerNewElementWizard$WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(DesignerNewElementWizard.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContex
`code`

Comment: So is this wizard based on `DesignerNewElementWizard` and you are trying to do work in the `finishPage(IProgressMonitor)` method? This is totally different to the normal wizard and my answer does not apply.

Comment: is there other way of using wizards? one which your solution works?

Comment: My answer is for code based on `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard` and `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`. DesignerNewElementWizard is an internal class and should not be used in any case.

Comment: got it...what if I use NewTypeWizardPage instead? will it work?

Comment: For anything like that you have to study the source to see how it is intended to be used. Again that appears to have a `finishPage` method which is already being run with a progress monitor so should just show a progress bar automatically.

Comment: right...the way my wizard is done, the progress bar is already there...just doesn´t have a label on it..